# ws_32.dll connect detouring hook no connect fails

Tags: c#, .net

I'm try to detour the connect function from the ws_32.dll. The detouring works, but something goes wrong when calling the orginal function. I use a relatively unknown library to hook the function. It is called WhiteMagic. It works with other functions well, just not this one.

I tried it on Internet Explorer and I can't connect anywhere. If I block with Thread.Sleep 100 ms, it works.

```
public static UIntPtr ConnectSocketDetoured(UIntPtr s, ref NativeSocks.sockaddr name, int namelen)
{
    Magic.Instance.Detours[DetouredConnectId].Remove();
    var retVal = ((NativeSocks.Dconnect)Magic.Instance.Detours[DetouredConnectId].TargetDelegate).Invoke(s, ref name, namelen);
    //var retVal = NativeSocks.connect(s, ref name, namelen); PINVOKE IMPORT DOESNT WORK TOO. 
    //IF I BLOCK HERE 100 MILLISECONDS THIS WORK.
    Magic.Instance.Detours[DetouredConnectId].Apply();

    return retVal;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = false)]
public delegate UIntPtr Dconnect(UIntPtr s, ref sockaddr_in name, int namelen);
```

---

sockaddr_in Struct

```
    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct sockaddr_in
    {
        public short sin_family;
        public ushort sin_port;
        public in_addr sin_addr;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string sin_zero;
    }

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct in_addr
    {
        public Anonymous1 S_un;
    }

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Anonymous1
    {
        [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public Anonymous2 S_un_b;

        [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public Anonymous3 S_un_w;

        [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public uint S_addr;
    }

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Anonymous2
    {
        public byte s_b1;
        public byte s_b2;
        public byte s_b3;
        public byte s_b4;
    }

    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Anonymous3
    {
        public ushort s_w1;
        public ushort s_w2;
    }
```

I think by blocking inside the detouring function while the hook is removed will cause a WSAEWOULDBLOCK error. For that reason, the internet explorer calls the connect function
again while the hook is removed and calls the original working function.

### WSAEWOULDBLOCK Error description :

Resource temporarily unavailable.
This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that cannot be completed immediately, for example recv when no data is queued to be read from the socket. 
It is a nonfatal error, and the operation should be retried later. It is normal for WSAEWOULDBLOCK to be reported as the result from calling connect on a nonblocking SOCK_STREAM socket, 
since some time must elapse for the connection to be established.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WhiteMagic but is there a reason you need to remove the hook and put it back? I did something the similar with Delphi / Winsock years ago and just left the hooks permanently in place and used other logic to modify / record incoming and outgoing data when necessary.

Comment: Need to remove it because i want to call the original function. Just want to obtain the function parameter data. but it is some time ago

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding of how the library works. In my case I wrote a Win32 DLL that mirrored the Winsock DLL functions and indexes, loaded the original version with an absolute path and mostly just passed things across apart from sending / receiving some data to my app via a mailslot. Anyway sounds like an old project but if it was something you wanted in the future guess my code could be moved to C++ fairly easily (don't use Delphi myself much now) and mailslots are pretty easy to use from .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your offer Peter. I had ended up with c++ and complete these project.  I saw you make some things with android too. Is it possible to write an IM here ?

Comment: Not sure about Android, I've only done a limited amount with it and nothing low-level.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using this WhiteMagic library: http://www.gamedeception.net/threads/17994-C-WhiteMagic-Injected-NET-Helper-Library

There is a method "CallOriginal" for each Detour. Try calling that instead of removing/reapplying your detour.

Answer (score -3):

Now assume you are using some `WhiteMagic` library.You should try using the method `CallOriginal` for each detour. You should call that instead of removing your detour.

Hope this helps.